# reading and updating a pandas df from a json file

Tags: python, pandas

i wrote two classes "orders" and "createfile" the latter is used to save/load/write pandas dataframe to a file.
i am trying to update a single cell in a pandas df(after loading out the saved df from the file) but either keep getting errors for different code or the code runs and the update does not happen. i will provide the class code and the desired result.

```py
In [2]: order_info = {
    "order id": Order.counter,
    "order status": self.status,
    "order time": self.time_placed,
    "table": self.table_number,
    "order items": items
}

order_info_df = pd.DataFrame([order_info])
order_info_df
```

```py
Out[2]
   order id order status     order time  table  order items
0         1       Placed  1683903935860    212  [leek, chicken]
```

i want to access a row based off of an "order id" and then update the value in the  "order items" column [leek, chicken]. i want to do this by having a list of "new items" and  concatenating with the list in the df cell

desired result:

```py
 order id order status     order time  table                   order items
0         1       Placed  1683903935860    212  [leek, chicken, steak, beef]
```

i have been trying to do this with the following code(and other variations using apply or lambda function) but have not managed

```py
existing_df.loc[existing_df['order id'] == self.order_id, 'order items'] += pd.Series(new_items)

 row_index = existing_df.loc[existing_df["order id"]
                                    == self.order_id].index[0]

        existing_df.at[row_index, "order items"].extend(new_items)
```

note: i am running this code inside a class method hence the "self"
and the new_item is a list like this

```py
new_items=["steak", "beef"]
```

i am trying to perform this inside of a class called "Order" and i wrote a class to save the df to a json file maybe my save method is whats interfering o will provide the code for both classes.

````py
class Order:

    order_df = pd.DataFrame()
    file_created = False
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, table_number,  status="Placed"):
        self.order_id = Order.counter
        self.table_number = table_number
        self.status = status
        self.time_placed = datetime.now()
        self.file_name = "order_data.json"
        Order.file_created = CreateFile.file_handler(
            self.file_name, Order.file_created)
        Order.counter += 1

    def create_order(self, items=[]):
        self.status = "Placed"
        self.time_placed = datetime.now()
        order_info = {
            "order id": Order.counter,
            "order status": self.status,
            "order time": self.time_placed,
            "table": self.table_number,
            "order items": items

        }

        Order.order_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([order_info])
        CreateFile.save_file(Order.order_df, self.file_name)

    def update_order(self, new_items=[]):
        existing_df = CreateFile.load("order_data.json")
        row_index = existing_df.loc[existing_df["order id"]
                                    == self.order_id].index[0]

        existing_df.at[row_index, "order items"].extend(new_items)

        CreateFile.save_file(existing_df, self.file_name)
         ```

and the class that takes care of loading and saving to the file:

```python
class CreateFile:
    @staticmethod
    def create_file(file_name):
        if os.path.exists(file_name):
            return
        with open(file_name, "w") as file:
            pass

    @staticmethod
    def save_file(data, file_name):
        existing_data = CreateFile.load(file_name)
        updated_data = existing_data.copy()
        updated_data.update(data)
        updated_data = pd.concat([updated_data, data], ignore_index=True)
        CreateFile.write_dataframe_to_json(updated_data, file_name)

    @staticmethod
    def load(file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
            content = file.read()
            if content.strip() == '':
                df = pd.DataFrame()
                return df
            else:
                df = pd.read_json(content)
        return df

    @staticmethod
    def write_dataframe_to_json(df, file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
            file.write(df.to_json(orient='records', indent=4))

    @staticmethod
    def file_handler(file_name, bool_value):
        if not bool_value:
            CreateFile.create_file(file_name)
            bool_value = True
            return bool_value
````